# Can't get metadata selector text

Tags: javascript, css-selectors, mocha.js, chai, puppeteer

This is a duplicate question to 
[node js puppeteer metadata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48900331/node-js-puppeteer-metadata)
At the time of writing this question I don't have enough reputation to comment on the question.
I am writing some test scripts for a project and I want to test some seo metadata tags.

I check my selector in the chrome dev tools and it works fine.

```
document.querySelectorAll("head > meta[name='description']")[0].content;
```

and I receive the data no problem

but when I try to get it to work inside my testing script I can't seem to get a hold of the selector.

```js
describe('guest jobs page', function () {
    const {expect} = require('chai');

    let page;

    before(async function () {
        page = await browser.newPage();
        await page.goto('https://page');
    });

    after(async function () {
        await page.close();
    })

    it('should have the correct page title', async function () {
        expect(await page.title()).to.eql('page - Jobs');
    });

    it('should have the correct page description', async function () {
        const DESCRIPTION_SELECTOR = "head > meta[name='description']";
        await console.log( await page.evaluate((DESCRIPTION_SELECTOR) => document.querySelectorAll(DESCRIPTION_SELECTOR)));
        expect(await page.$eval(DESCRIPTION_SELECTOR, element => element.textContent)).to.eql('page description content');
//this fails as no content is returned
//AssertionError: expected '' to deeply equal 'page description content'

    });
});
```

any help would be appreciated, I don't know how to attach this question to the previous one without commenting so if someone could enlighten me about that I would also be very grateful. Thanks.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: Please show your puppeteer code then.

Comment: @Vaviloff
can you please look at my my edited question? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe `console.log` will be empty because `DESCRIPTION_SELECTOR` is undefined inside of `page.evaluate`.

In order to use a variable from the main script inside of `page.evaluate` one must explicitly pass it into the evaluating function:

```
await page.evaluate(DESCRIPTION_SELECTOR => document.querySelectorAll(DESCRIPTION_SELECTOR), DESCRIPTION_SELECTOR);
```

This is because `page.evaluate` operates in a kind of a sandbox and only has access to functions and variables declared at the web page opened by `puppeteer` (the so called "page context"). Since that page has no `DESCRIPTION_SELECTOR`, we must pass it in arguments of the `page.evaluate`, after the function to be evaluated. See also: [documentation](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageevaluatepagefunction-args)

As for `page.$eval`, it returns empty string because there is no `textContent` in meta tag, you need to use just `content`:

```
page.$eval(DESCRIPTION_SELECTOR, element => element.content)
```